# How to translate this Queryable linq function

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm struggling trying to generate this LINQ function in a correct T-SQL function.

Please check the following sentence:

```
// determine the max count of exams applied by students
IQueryable query = (from at in Database.Current.AnsweredTests
                    where at.TestId == id
                    group at by at.StudentId into s
                    select s.Count()).Max();
```

As you can see this function is wrong talking about syntactically, because `Max` extension returns `int`. So which I'm trying to accomplish is to generate a correct T-SQL.

Something like this:

```
MAX(SELECT x.COUNT()
FROM...
GROUP BY StudentId)
```

I just did this because I want a good performance, and that is performing a low performance. So my problem is how can I write a correct LINQ sentence with the aggregate functions like `MAX` and `COUNT`.

UPDATE:

```
SELECT [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[StudentId] AS [K1], 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[AnsweredTests] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  CAST( [Extent1].[TestId] AS int) = @p__linq__0
    GROUP BY [Extent1].[StudentId]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

This is what generate the IQueryable (if I remove the max extension, of course). I would like to know if is there a way to include the aggregate function MAX inside of that T-SQL Query to improve the performance on the Server side.

Comment: What SQL is your IQueryable producing as written?

Comment: @DarfZon are you sure your desired SQL is correct?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky of course, am I missing something?

Comment: Side comment but that `CAST` looks like an ugly index-blocking problem. Not sure if it's an uncontrollable artifact or you have a type mismatch somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could also word your query in the following way:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*)
FROM AnsweredTests
WHERE TestId = @id
GROUP BY StudentId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Following that logic, this (untested) should be what you are looking for:

```
var result = (from at in Database.Current.AnsweredTests
              where at.TestId == id
              group at by at.StudentId into s
              orderby s.Count() descending
              select s.Count()).First()
```

Comment: I see but how can I do for my LINQ FUNCTION has an output like the T-SQL code you've posted?

Comment: @DarfZon Sorry I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted T-SQL from the query.

Comment: @DarfZon Updated. This should be what you are looking for provided it works

Answer (score 0):

You can do `ORDER BY DESCENDING` and then take first:

```
var Max = (from at in Database.Current.AnsweredTests
           where at.TestId == id
           group at by at.StudentId into s
           select new { Count = s.Count() }).OrderByDescending(o=>o.Count).First();
```